# Is っていうんですか／っていうんだ used for emphasis in the context?

Tags: pattern

> 1. 「それで……令音さん、夕弦は一体どこに消えた**っていうんですか**？」

Context: 夕弦 vanished and 士道 was asking about her whereabouts.

> 2. 耶俱矢「さぁて、忘れてはおらぬだろうな。我らが聖戦の前に交わした契約を！」 士道「ちゃんと覚えてるよ。……んで？一体何させよう**っていうんだ**？」

Context:
耶俱矢 and 士道 entered a competition and agreed that the winner could order the loser to do something. And as a result, 士道 lost.

Hi. I understand the meanings of the sentences in question are “Where on earth did 夕弦 disappear to?” and “What on earth do you want me to do?” respectively.
I am wondering if the bold っていうんですか and っていうんだ have the same function, namely, emphasizing the question? Can we use っていうんですか and っていうんだ interchangeably in both examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

っていうんですか and っていうんだ literally mean "(What/Where) do you say" or "(What/Where) are you saying". But they can be used when there is no listener in particular, too, so thinking of them as "on earth", "the hell", etc., is basically fine. However, you should use this only when there is something still unclear and you want more detail. Saying っていうんだ/ですか at the beginning of a conversation would sound fairly sudden and unnatural.

For example, imagine that you are walking alone on the beach and suddenly a large monster appears out of the water. You may say "What the hell is that!?" in English, but you cannot say あれは何だっていうんだ because there is no previous context.

> Can we use っていうんですか and っていうんだ interchangeably in both examples?

No. As usual, the です-style and the だ-style cannot be mixed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. By the way, can we omit the っていうんですか and っていうんだ in those examples?